# Laravel 4 Populate a Dropdown list with 2 Database Columns?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

```
echo Form::select(
    'campaign_user_id',
    User::find(1)->profile->lists('first_name', 'id'),
    Input::get('campaign_user_id', $campaign->user_id),
    array(
      "placeholder" => "US",
      'class' => 'form-control',
      'disabled' => 'disabled'
    )
)
```

The code above is used to build a Dropdown selection list.  It fetches a list of Users from the database.  On line 3 you can see `User::find(1)->profile->lists('first_name', 'id')`

It is getting the first_name column, I need to somehow get first and last name columns though and combine them in this list.  So that list value is still user ID and Full name is shown.

Any idea how to make this work with 2 DB columns `first_name` and `last_name`?  Or another method to reach my end goal?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

// In your model

```
class User extends Eloquent
{
    public function getFullNameAttribute()
    {
        return $this->attributes['first_name'] . ' ' . $this->attributes['last_name'];
    }
}
```

then grab like so:

```
User::find(1)->profile->lists('full_name', 'id');
```

OR

```
User::find(1)->profile->select(DB::raw('concat (first_name," ",last_name) as full_name,id'))->lists('full_name', 'id');
```

I prefer the first one :)

Comment: Just a note, The first method gave me this error... `Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'full_name' in 'field list' (SQL: select `full_name`, `id` from `profiles`)` the 2nd worked though, thanks.  I also tried adding the `getFullNameAttribute()` method to my `User` and `Profile` models but still got that error.